# How can I avoid CS8618 warning occur at the point of declaration?

Tags: c#, nullable

Assuming the following C# code (and assuming nullable is on):

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar;
}

var foo = new Foo { Bar = "some value" };
```

How can I avoid a CS8618 warning declaring Bar without a default value, but instead only get warning when attempting to construct a Foo without initializing it?  I.e., the above to me seems fine, but the following should generate a warning (convertible to an error):

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar;
}

var foo = new Foo { };
```

As Bar is a non-nullable string and therefore a Foo cannot be created without providing a value for it.
I ask because the code base I'm converting to have nullable turned on has a lot of this sort of thing.  I can work around it by assigning a default dummy value to each such property, but then the compiler *won't* catch cases where a Foo is getting created without its properties being properly initialized. The only other solution seems to be to write explicit constructors for all such classes, but some of them have 15+ properties, and (IMO) it actually makes the code less readable - esp. because there's no way of enforcing named parameters, so a call like `new TextBox { Color = Color.Red, Width = 15, Height = 20, Title = "My Box", FontFace = "Arial" }` can become `new TextBox(Color.Red, 15, 20, "Arial", "My Box")`, which is definitely not preferable for hopefully obvious reasons. It seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a constructor for the class?

Comment: Yes, I explained why I wasn't keen on that alternative.

Comment: Seems this is discussed here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2830

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`required`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) modifier in C# 11.

```
class Foo
{
    public required string Bar; // no nullability warnings
}

var foo = new Foo { Bar = "some value" };

var foo2 = new Foo { }; // won't compile
```

Comment: You could also mark the setter as init only. public string Bar { get; init; }

Comment: @TheEvilMetal, an init setter wouldn't get rid of the nullability warning, and neither would it make the compiler enforce setting Bar's value when creating Foo's instances, both of which are things the OP wants.

Comment: Great, thanks - will try that.  What affect does that have on ability to create in a generic function (does such a type still satisfy : new() ?) or via reflection?

Comment: A type with required members doesn't satisfy the new() generic constraint, and I don't know about reflection - I think you can probably make an instance via reflection just fine.

Comment: Yep, construction by reflection (as used by Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject) appears to work fine and creates the element with a null member despite it being required. 
  System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize() throws an error though.

Comment: Unfortunately using "required" seems to require upgrading to .NET 7 (or later)? The project sitll uses .NET framework 4.7 and trying to use it generates "error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerFeatureRequiredAttribute..ctor'
"

Comment: `required` is a feature of C# 11, which is supported on .NET 7 and newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [null-forgiving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) assignment -

```
public string Bar = null!;
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still let me create a Foo without initialising Bar, with no warning.